# Ruby On Rails, Redis::CommandError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, redis-rails

Why does this code

```
redis.set("test", true, ex: 24.hours)
```

return the following exception?

```
Redis::CommandError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
```

I use these gems

- redis (3.2.0)
- redis-rails (4.0.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a problem with the redis version, check this for more information: https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/372

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this. More specifically, Redis versions before 2.6.12 don't support passing additional arguments to SET and similar commands.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is correct. You need to update Redis. If you're on mac, follow these steps to quickly update Redis:

1. go to http://redis.io/download and download the latest version
2. unpack it and go to that folder in the console
3. `$ make`
4. `$ make install`

And if you have an older version of Redis running at the moment, kill it:

5. `$ ps -ef | grep redis`, the PID is the 2nd number on the 1st row
6. `sudo kill <the PID>`

That's it

Comment: or `sudo pkill redis`